# uwsgi can't load app when set up nginx+django service on centos

Tags: django, nginx, centos, uwsgi

centos7, python3.6.3,django1.11, uwsgi2.0.15
when i run command 'uwsgi --ini djcode_uwsgi.ini', no app is loaded,the message is as below:

> 

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from djcode_uwsgi.ini
    > open("/usr/lib64/uwsgi/python3_plugin.so"): No such file or directory
    > [core/utils.c line 3686] !!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin:
    > /usr/lib64/uwsgi/python3_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No
    > such file or directory !!!
    > *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Sat Oct  7 16:47:06 2017] *** compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) on 19 May
    > 2017 14:33:49 os: Linux-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4
    > 15:04:05 UTC 2017 nodename: izuf64a9gck8o1inxenp1cz machine: x86_64
    > clock source: unix pcre jit disabled detected number of CPU cores: 1
    > current working directory: /home/djcode detected binary path:
    > /usr/sbin/uwsgi uWSGI running as root, you can use
    > --uid/--gid/--chroot options
    > *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***  chdir() to /home/djcode your processes number limit is 3889 your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number:
    > 65535 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes thunder lock: disabled (you
    > can enable it with --thunder-lock) uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address
    > :8001 fd 3 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100
    > connections your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60
    > seconds mapped 363840 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
    > *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
    > *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
    > *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7787) spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7788, cores:
    > 1) spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 7789, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 3
    > (pid: 7790, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 7791, cores: 1)
```

the settings in django_uwsgi.ini:

> ```
> #wsgi.ini file
> [uwsgi]
> plugin = python3
> # Django-related settings
>
> socket = :8001
> callable = app
> # the base directory (full path)
> chdir           = /home/djcode
>
> # Django s wsgi file
> module          = djcode.wsgi
>
> # process-related settings
> # master
> master          = true
>
> # maximum number of worker processes
> processes       = 4
>
> # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
> # chmod-socket    = 664
> # clear environment on exit
> vacuum          = true
> ```

I've install uwsgi-plugin-python. any suggestion?

i install uwsgi-plugin-python3 now, the error message now is as below:

> [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from djcode_uwsgi.ini
>   *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Sat Oct  7 18:07:27 2017]**  compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) on 19 May
>   2017 14:33:49 os: Linux-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4
>   15:04:05 UTC 2017 nodename: izuf64a9gck8o1inxenp1cz machine: x86_64
>   clock source: unix pcre jit disabled detected number of CPU cores: 1
>   current working directory: /home/djcode detected binary path:
>   /usr/sbin/uwsgi uWSGI running as root, you can use
>   --uid/--gid/--chroot options
>    **WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag)**   chdir() to /home/djcode your processes number limit is 3889 your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number:
>   65535 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes thunder lock: disabled (you
>   can enable it with --thunder-lock) uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address
>   :8001 fd 3 Python version: 3.4.5 (default, May 29 2017, 15:17:55) 
>   [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
>    **Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads**  Python main interpreter initialized at 0x12e9940 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections your
>   mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds mapped 363840
>   bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
>    **Operational MODE: preforking**  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./djcode/**init**.py", line 1, in 
>       import pymysql ImportError: No module named 'pymysql' unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
>    **no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode** 
>    **uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 8035) spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 8036, cores:
>   1) spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 8037, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 3
>   (pid: 8038, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 8039, cores: 1)

remove plugin = python3:

> [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from djcode_uwsgi.ini
>   *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Sat Oct  7 21:37:08 2017]**  compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) on 19 May
>   2017 14:33:49 os: Linux-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4
>   15:04:05 UTC 2017 nodename: izuf64a9gck8o1inxenp1cz machine: x86_64
>   clock source: unix pcre jit disabled detected number of CPU cores: 1
>   current working directory: /home/djcode detected binary path:
>   /usr/sbin/uwsgi uWSGI running as root, you can use
>   --uid/--gid/--chroot options
>    **WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag)**   chdir() to /home/djcode your processes number limit is 3889 your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number:
>   65535 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes thunder lock: disabled (you
>   can enable it with --thunder-lock) uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address
>   :8001 fd 3 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100
>   connections your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60
>   seconds mapped 363840 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
>    **Operational MODE: preforking** 
>    **no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode** 
>    **uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 8387) spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 8388, cores:
>   1) spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 8389, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 3
>   (pid: 8390, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 8391, cores: 1)

change callable=application:

> [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from djcode_uwsgi.ini
>   *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Thu Oct 12 15:42:00 2017]**  compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) on 19 May
>   2017 14:33:49 os: Linux-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4
>   15:04:05 UTC 2017 nodename: izuf64a9gck8o1inxenp1cz machine: x86_64
>   clock source: unix pcre jit disabled detected number of CPU cores: 1
>   current working directory: /home/djcode detected binary path:
>   /usr/sbin/uwsgi uWSGI running as root, you can use
>   --uid/--gid/--chroot options
>    **WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag)**   chdir() to /home/djcode your processes number limit is 3889 your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number:
>   65535 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes thunder lock: disabled (you
>   can enable it with --thunder-lock) uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address
>   :8001 fd 3 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100
>   connections your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60
>   seconds mapped 363840 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
>    **Operational MODE: preforking** 
>    **no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode** 
>    **uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17756) spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17757, cores:
>   1) spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 17758, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker
>   3 (pid: 17759, cores: 1) spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 17760, cores: 1)

Comment: remove `plugin = python3` from your ini

Comment: pymysql is imported, but still no app loaded

Comment: Update the new message in question

Comment: updated.........

Comment: What is the content of `djcode/wsgi.py`?

Comment: import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djcode.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: Change `callable = app` to `callable = application` and then try again

Comment: updated, same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed the wrong package.

Try by installing uwsgi-plugin-python3.

Comment: remove the old one and reinstall uwsgi-plugin-python3, nothing changes

Comment: edited in my question.import pymysql ImportError: No module named 'pymysql' , i need to import pymysql in my __init__.py.  this error was solved when i install uwsgi-plugin-python

Comment: The problem is given in error trace itself:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "./djcode/init.py", line 1, in import pymysql ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'